# For any integer $n>0$ there is always a prime $p$ with $q_n\leq{p}\leq{3n}$ or $3n\leq{p}\leq{q_n}$ , where $q_n$ is the $n$-th prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I checked it for all the prime $\leq{100}$, the results seem very obvious though, so I would love a proof or two and any correction and opinion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement is incorrect (at least) for all $n\le 11$. $q_{12}=37>36=3\cdot12$ is the first such occurrence.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, after $q_11$ $q_n$ gets bigger than $3n$. My point was to say that there is at least one prime between $3n$ and $q_n$, whether one is greater than the other. I'm correcting/editing the statement. Thanks @VincenzoOliva

Comment: No it is not. I said said **less than or equal to**, therefore in your case there are two primes 2 and 3, which is more than one. The statement still holds. @uniquesolution

Comment: No I didn't actually attempt a proof. I had know idea how to proceed to prove my statement. Thanks. @SultanofSwing

Answer (score 1):

We know that:
$$q_n\sim n*log\ n$$
$log\ n$ grows, so from some point on, there will be so much space inbetween $3n$ and $q_n$ that it will work for most numbers. You can take any number instead of $3$ and this will still be true.

Comment: Perfectly understood. Thanks for the answer. @Mastrem